# Choosing an Inductor for MAX8792

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inductor, step-down

I want to make sure I chose the right inductor value for [MAX8792](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX8792.pdf).

My step down converter should convert 12V to 1.8V while delivering maximum 3A at the output.

this is a schematic that was used to convert 12V to 1.2V with 15.38A maximum current at output:

[image]

I need to replace the  0.82uH, Isat=24A, 6.8mohm DCR with a new one that is suitable for 1.8V output.
according to the L formula:

[image]

The inductor I need is: \$\frac{12-1.8}{346\cdot10^{3} \cdot 3.2[A]\cdot0.247}\$x\$\frac{1.8}{12}\$ = 5.59 uH.

Note: I chose LIR (ripple percentage) to be 24.7% (The optimum operating point is usually found between 20% and 50% ripple current, according to datasheet), and it's the same value that could be calculated from the formula by substituting all the parameters in the 1.2V output design.

I have 6.8uH, Irated>=3.8A, DCR=0.022 oHm [inductor](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/679294/MurataManufacturing/LQH88P/1) in my stock. is this a good choice?

Comment: what other requirments do you have? ripple, response time and so on?

Comment: @AntonIngemarson, good question. this voltage is a 1.8V Primary Voltage for Intel Tiger Lake UP3 CPU. I didn't dig deep regarding what ripple is allowed to this voltage. I need to check in the datasheets or consult with their support. Thank you.

Comment: Check carefully the ripple requirements . This is an incomplete spec: "The optimum operating point is usually found between 20% and 50% ripple current" You also must spec the target voltage ripple allowed. For CPU supply you need very low ripple voltage, although it will be still regulated to a lower voltage close to the CPU. But I doubt that more than 100 mV would be acceptable.